# MVC - Displaying a List of Files in a View

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following MVC code:

```
@model ExchangeSite.Entities.BicycleSellerListing


    <fieldset>
    <legend>Images</legend>

        <div>
            <div class="imagelabel">
                Image #1
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="file" name="[0].files" id="files_0" style="width:275px"/>
            </div>

            <div class="imagelabel">
                Image #2
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="file" name="[1].files" id="files_1" style="width:275px"/>
            </div>

            <div class="imagelabel">
                Image #3
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="file" name="[2].files" id="files_2" style="width:275px"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Here is my model / entity, or at least a portion of it:

```
public class BicycleSellerListing
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)]
    public int BicycleSellerListingId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BicycleImage> ImageList { get; set; }
}
```

When the associated controller is called, I retrieve the files the user has already uploaded to the system (a max of three) from our database. What I don't know how to do is to display the names of those files in the MVC view shown above.

Comment: randy, these are file uploaders. Do you want to display the file names before uploading them?

Comment: @DaveA - Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I want to display the names of the files the user has already uploaded so he/she can add more or delete them.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here and what problems are you encountering. Could you reformulate your question? What does the model you have shown has to do with the view?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I am trying to figure out how to take some files my controller reads from the database (and stores them in ImageList) and display the names of those files in my view, given the view code I have shown above. I don't know what the controller code should look like to get the files names to appear in the view

Comment: But the view you have shown contains file inputs which are used for uploading files to the server. Where and when do you want to display those filenames?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Let me rephrase the problem. I have a view where the user can upload up to three files to a database. The view you see above does this. I want to allow the user, when he/she wants to, to see what files he/she has uploaded and possibly add more or remove them. I'd like to use the same view to do both. This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the list of files in your model (`MyList` in the example below) and then on your view you could razor's `foreach` to iterate over your list and repeat the html. Something like this (notice you can pull the Id from the item too):

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Images</legend>

    <div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyList) {    
        <div class="imagelabel">
                Image #1
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>@item.FileName</div>
            </div>
          }     
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Updated:** replaced input elements with divs.